# How Can make my query dynamic, I found error inside this query? System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found 'Regional'

Tags: apex, soql

```
 String userFields = 'user.id, user.profile.name';
    String profileName = 'Regional CS Team Member';        
    String userObject = 'user, user.profile';
    String userCondition = 'user.profile.name = "Regional CS Team Member"';
    String userANDCondition = 'user.IsActive= TRUE ';
    String userQuery = 'SELECT '+ userFields + ' FROM ' + userObject + ' WHERE '+ userCondition + ' AND ' + userANDCondition + ' ORDER BY name ASC ';
    System.debug(userQuery);

     //put the list for get the user id 
    List<User> lstOfUsers = Database.query(userQuery);

    String oppFields = 'Id, Name, Amount ';
    String oppObject = ' Opportunity ';
    String oppCondition = ' CreatedById IN :  ';
    String oppANDCondition = ' AND Amount != Null AND Amount != 0 ';        
    String oppQuery = ' SELECT '+ oppFields+' FROM '+oppObject+' WHERE '+ oppCondition + lstOfUsers + oppANDCondition;
    System.debug(oppQuery);
    
    //get the records of opportunity
   List<Opportunity> fetchAllRelatedOpp = Database.query(oppQuery);
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I am using here my dynamic query to found out the user records and opportunity records to get the data

I am going to provide link of my another question
[enter link description here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/402874/how-can-i-find-the-opportunity-records-with-respect-to-user-and-users-profile-w/402917#402917)

```
public with sharing class WeeklyEngagemnt{    
 static map<string,integer> weekDaysToNumber = new map<string,integer>{ 'Monday'=>0,
                                                                        'Tuesday'=>1,
                                                                        'Wednesday'=>2,
                                                                        'Thursday'=>3,
                                                                        'Friday'=>4,
                                                                        'Saturday'=>5,
                                                                        'Sunday'=>6};         
//get the weeks from the method of 'getMyDates'                                                                    
 public static List<date> getMyDates(string dayOfWeekName, integer month, integer year){
    List<date> returnList = new List<date>();
    date d = date.newInstance(year,month,1);
    d=d.addDays(math.mod(7-dayOfWeek(d)+weekDaysToNumber.get(dayOfWeekName),7));
    do{
        returnList.add(d);
        d=d.addDays(7);
    } while(d.month()==month);
    return returnList;
}
public static integer dayOfWeek(date d){
    return math.mod(date.newInstance(1900,1,8).daysBetween(d),7); 
}
/*
public WeeklyEngagemnt(){
    String userFields = 'user.profile.name';
    String profileName = 'Regional CS Team Member';
    String oppFields = 'Name,Amount';
} //how we can user the string varible inside our method fetchAllRelatedOpportunity 
*/
public static void fetchAllRelatedOpportunity(){
    //Create list of date 
    List<Date> lstOfDates = WeeklyEngagemnt.getMyDates('Monday',4,2023);        
    Decimal total = 0;  
    String userFields = 'user.id, user.profile.name';
    String profileName = 'Regional CS Team Member';        
    String userObject = 'user, user.profile';
    String userCondition = 'user.profile.name =: ';
    String userANDCondition = 'user.IsActive= TRUE ';
    String userQuery = 'SELECT '+ userFields + ' FROM ' + userObject + ' WHERE '+ userCondition + profileName + ' AND ' +
                        userANDCondition + ' ORDER BY name ASC ';
    System.debug(userQuery);
    
    //put the list for get the user id 
    List<User> lstOfUsers = Database.query(userQuery);
    
    String oppFields = 'Id, Name, Amount ';
    String oppObject = ' Opportunity ';
    String oppCondition = ' CreatedById IN :  ';
    String oppANDCondition = ' AND Amount != Null AND Amount != 0 ';        
    String oppQuery = ' SELECT '+ oppFields+' FROM '+oppObject+' WHERE '+ oppCondition + lstOfUsers + oppANDCondition;
    System.debug(oppQuery);
    
    //get the records of opportunity
   List<Opportunity> fetchAllRelatedOpp = Database.query(oppQuery);  
    
    //Updated opportuntiy list
    List<Opportunity> lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();         
     
    //Map of user Id with list of Dates
   Map<Id,List<Date>> userByweekClosedWonValue = new Map<Id,List<Date>>();       
    for(User objUser: lstOfUsers){
        if(lstOfUsers.size()>0){
            userByweekClosedWonValue.put(objUser.Id, lstOfDates);               
        }
    }
    if(fetchAllRelatedOpp.size()>0){
         for( Opportunity objOppo : fetchAllRelatedOpp){           
            total = total+objOppo.Amount;     
             lstOpp.add(objOppo);                
        }            
    }    
    
    system.debug('listOfOppo ===> ' + lstOpp); 
    System.debug('Total: '+total);

}
```

}

Comment: It may well be one of many errors, but you should change the `userCondition` to `String userCondition = 'user.profile.name = :profileName;'.

Comment: @AdrianLarson please chek it once I have edit the code

Comment: Please don't change your question to reflect code changes suggested by comments or answers. It makes existing things lose their context (and thus makes it harder to read). If you feel that you _must_ address a code issue, keeping the original and making an extra section to say "and this is what it looks like after change x/y/z"

Comment: Similar to what @AdrianLarson said, in the oppQuery's oppCondition, you should use `CreatedById IN :lstOfUsers` to benefit from a binding, and not concatenate in the `lstOfUsers` at all. It seems likely you should review [SOQL on trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_soql).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to ask is whether or not this query needs to be dynamic. With what you've shown thus far, the answer to that question is definitely "no, this does not need to be a dynamic query".

Dynamic queries introduce additional complications, and any errors in them will only be found at run-time (as opposed to at compile time).

Assuming that you're trying to learn here rather than seriously trying to use this query for actual work...

### The main issue

is with `String userCondition = 'user.profile.name = "Regional CS Team Member"';`
SOQL (and Apex, for that matter) doesn't use double quotes to enclose strings.

If you need to put a string inside of a string, then you need to escape the single quotes with a backslash.
`String userCondition = 'user.profile.name = \'Regional CS Team Member\'';`

The backslash tells Apex (or rather, the compiler) "yes, this is a [thing], but don't treat it how you normally would".

### Other issues

- You don't need to prefix "user" to fields of the `User` SObject when the primary SObject for your query is `User`
- Using `'user, user.profile'` for the `FROM` in your first query is unnecessary. It *can* be used to reduce typing when you're working with multiple levels of parent records, but you're not using that here. You should only query on `User` here
- You've already created a string to hold "Regional CS Team Member", so `userCondition` should use a simple variable bind, e.g. `String myCondition = 'Name = :otherVariable';`.
- `String oppCondition = ' CreatedById IN :  ';` is wrong. The variable that you're using in the variable bind must be part of the string.

Variable binds in dynamic SOQL also have additional restrictions (namely, that you cannot use dot notation to try to reference a specific field or property). In my own testing, it appears that `CreatedById IN :lstOfUsers` should work (as would passing in something like a `List<String>`).

### Final thoughts

String concatenation like this is messy and prone to issues. Dynamic SOQL needs whitespace between the keywords and stuff like field names and sobject names. While you do appear to have that here, it's something that's easy to miss and trips many people up.

Instead of that, using `String.format()` can be a better idea. To give you an idea of how you might use that...

```java
List<String> fieldAPINames = new List<String>{'Id', 'Profile.Name'};
String profileName = 'Regional CS Team Member'; 
String queryString = String.format(
    // The {0}, {1}, etc... are placeholders, which are substituted with that
    //   index in the subsequent list that you provide to this method
    'SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE {2} ORDER BY {3}',
    new List<Object>{
        // Simple string lists can be used with a simple String.join()
        // Other things (especially dates in the WHERE clause) would
        //   need more special handling
        String.join(fieldAPINames, ', '),
        // Plain 'ol strings are fine
        'User',
        // Simple binds are fine
        'IsActive = true AND Profile.Name = :profileName',
        'Name ASC'
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Now code working fine for dynamic query

Answer (score 0):

```
public with sharing class WeeklyEngagemnt{    
 static map<string,integer> weekDaysToNumber = new map<string,integer>{ 'Monday'=>0,
                                                                        'Tuesday'=>1,
                                                                        'Wednesday'=>2,
                                                                        'Thursday'=>3,
                                                                        'Friday'=>4,
                                                                        'Saturday'=>5,
                                                                        'Sunday'=>6};         
//get the weeks from the method of 'getMyDates'                                                                    
 public static List<date> getMyDates(string dayOfWeekName, integer month, integer year){
    List<date> returnList = new List<date>();
    date d = date.newInstance(year,month,1);
    d=d.addDays(math.mod(7-dayOfWeek(d)+weekDaysToNumber.get(dayOfWeekName),7));
    do{
        returnList.add(d);
        d=d.addDays(7);
    } while(d.month()==month);
    return returnList;
}
public static integer dayOfWeek(date d){
    return math.mod(date.newInstance(1900,1,8).daysBetween(d),7); 
}
/*
public WeeklyEngagemnt(){
    String userFields = 'user.profile.name';
    String profileName = 'Regional CS Team Member';
    String oppFields = 'Name,Amount';
} //how we can user the string varible inside our method fetchAllRelatedOpportunity 
*/
public static void fetchAllRelatedOpportunity(){
    //Create list of date 
    List<Date> lstOfDates = WeeklyEngagemnt.getMyDates('Monday',4,2023);        
    Decimal total = 0;        
    String userFields = 'user.id, user.profile.name';
    String profileName = 'Regional CS Team Member';        
    String userObject = 'user, user.profile';
    String userCondition = 'user.profile.name = \'Regional CS Team Member\'';
    String userANDCondition = 'user.IsActive= TRUE ';
    String userQuery = 'SELECT '+ userFields + ' FROM ' + userObject + ' WHERE '+ userCondition + ' AND ' +
                        userANDCondition + ' ORDER BY name ASC ';
    System.debug(userQuery);
    
    //put the list for get the user id 
    List<User> lstOfUsers = Database.query(userQuery);        
    String oppFields = 'Id, Name, Amount ';
    String oppObject = ' Opportunity ';
    String oppCondition = ' CreatedById IN : lstOfUsers ';
    String oppANDCondition = ' AND Amount != Null AND Amount != 0 ';        
    String oppQuery = ' SELECT '+ oppFields+' FROM '+oppObject+' WHERE '+ oppCondition + oppANDCondition;
    System.debug(oppQuery);
     
    //get the records of opportunity
   List<Opportunity> fetchAllRelatedOpp = Database.query(oppQuery);  
    
    //Updated opportuntiy list
    List<Opportunity> lstOpp = new List<Opportunity>();         
     
    //Map of user Id with list of Dates
   Map<Id,List<Date>> userByweekClosedWonValue = new Map<Id,List<Date>>();       
    for(User objUser: lstOfUsers){
        if(lstOfUsers.size()>0){
            userByweekClosedWonValue.put(objUser.Id, lstOfDates);               
        }
    }
    if(fetchAllRelatedOpp.size()>0){
         for( Opportunity objOppo : fetchAllRelatedOpp){           
            total = total+objOppo.Amount;     
             lstOpp.add(objOppo);                
        }            
    }    
    
    system.debug('listOfOppo ===> ' + lstOpp); 
    System.debug('Total: '+total);

}
```

}

Now my Dynamic query working fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. To help with others that might face the same issue you should explain what you've done and why it now works for you. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question you asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in [the help center](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).